# How can I use for loop for these process in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that includes 43 different countries.
To summarize my data frame, row names like that: (AUS1, AUS2, AUS3, ... BRA1, BRA2, ... GER1, GER2...GER56) and there is a variable like Country which includes country codes.

I need to find their export values. I can find separately but, it is taking so much time because I have 14 different years. Thus, I want to use for loop. However, I can not find any way to use for loop for the below process.

This is my code to find export for single country.

```
##AUT

AUT <- filter(wiot, wiot$Country == "AUT")
exportAUT <- sum(AUT$TOT) - sum(select(AUT, starts_with("AUT")))

##BEL

BEL <- filter(wiot, wiot$Country == "BEL")
exportBEL <- sum(BEL$TOT) - sum(select(BEL, starts_with("BEL")))
```

Comment: Your life would be so much easier if you kept your data in long format (i.e., [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)) and not wide format with suffixed columns.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create individually named objects for this set of results is the path to madness in R. Instead create a list with a more generic name and then put results in the "leaves" (individual element) inside the list:

```
 export <- list()
 for (i in wiot$Country) { 
               export[i] <- sum(wiot[i]$TOT) - sum(select(wiot, starts_with(i)))
       #or maybe: export[i] <- sum(wiot[i]$TOT) - sum(wiot[ grepl(i,names(wiot)) ] )
                          }
```

This is a guess, since I'm not able to figure out how the rows and columns are referenced in your data.frame object. It would be much easier to debug this if you provided a less ambiguous description of the data object named `wiot`. Use either the output of `str(wiot)` or show output of `dput(head(wiot))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `by` to build a named list of *export* calculations:

```
export_list <- by(wiot, wiot$country, function(sub)
   sum(sub$TOT) - sum(select(sub, starts_with(sub$country[1])))
)

export_list$AUT
export_list$BEL
export_list$GER
...
```